# JavaCV grab frame method delays and returns old frames

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm trying to create a video player in Java using JavaCV and its FFmpegFrameGrabber class. Simply, Inside a loop, I use

**.grab()** to get a frame and then **paint it on a panel**

**Problem is, player gets delayed.** For example, after 30 seconds passes, in video only 20 seconds passes.

Source is ok. Other players can play the stream normally. Problem is possibly the long printing time.

What I do not understand is that : **"why does .grab() method brings me a frame from 10 seconds ago ?"** Shouldn't it just grab the frame which is being streamed at the moment ?

(Sorry for not providing a working code, it's all over different huge classes)

I use the following grabber options (selected by some other colleague):

```
grabber.setImageHeight(480);
grabber.setImageWidth(640);
grabber.setOption("reconnect", "1");
grabber.setOption("reconnect_at_eof", "1");
grabber.setOption("reconnect_streamed", "1");
grabber.setOption("reconnect_delay_max", "2");
grabber.setOption("preset", "veryfast");
grabber.setOption("probesize", "192");
grabber.setOption("tune", "zerolatency");
grabber.setFrameRate(30.0);
grabber.setOption("buffer_size", "" + this.bufferSize);
grabber.setOption("max_delay", "500000");
grabber.setOption("stimeout", String.valueOf(6000000));
grabber.setOption("loglevel", "quiet");
grabber.start();
```

Thanks

Comment: idk if it's too late but ffmpeg holds a buffer queue with recent frames, you'll have to read its frames before this queue gets filled, otherwise you will start losing frames because FFMpeg drops frames when whit queue is filled

Comment: check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185079/ffmpeg-javacv-latency-issue/59473234#59473234